# Half angle sine substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

After learning the Weierstrass substitution, I wondered what would happen if I tried doing a half angle sine substitution. Using the formula $$\sin\frac{x}{2}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}{2}}$$I derived that $\cos x=1-2s^2$, where $s=\sin\frac{x}2$. So when is this substitution a good idea to use? I am thinking it is best when there are cosines and secants, but that is a very rough criterion.

Comment: It's useful in the integration of the arclength of a cycloid: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Length_of_Arc_of_Cycloid/Proof_1

Comment: @boojum I guess… didn’t know that though.

Comment: I think you need more than a prevalence of $\cos$/$\sec$ terms for the substitution to be effective. You end up with$$\int f(\cos(x),\sec(x))\,dx=2\int f\left(1-2s^2,\frac1{1-2s^2}\right)\,\frac{ds}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}$$which I imagine is easy to compute only for a small set of cases.